# Gradient background using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, background, gradient

I want to create a background with grain effect and using radial gradient. Is that possible to do with css "background" property only? Can you please help me with it? It should look something like that, just without the picture on the right, thanks! (cant post pics here, because I need more reputation points)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the background-image radial gradient property.
For example
{
background-image: radial-gradient(red, green, blue)
}